# Is there a way to hide the "peek problem" link from monaco editor's marker widget?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm looking for a configurable way (not css styling override) to not show the "Peek Problem" link 
at the footer of the Monaco editor marker widget (the one that appears when hovering an error/marked item)

[image]

Thanks!